# Jenkins+Docker: commit the changes from docker.inside()

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a docker image which needs to be propagated to a higher environment. As such, I need to create another image from the current one and the only difference is a config file. I was wondering if there's an easy way to do it using Jenkins docker pipeline.

```
stage('Build Image') {

    steps {
       script{                                 
            docker.image('${env.IMG_NM}:${env.IMG_TAG}').inside {
                sh 'cp ${WORKSPACE}/config.txt /path_to_my_config/config.txt'
            }                                    
        }
    }            
}
```

In this step I pull an dgo into the existing docker image and copy the file over. I am not sure as to how to proceed from here. How do I commit this docker container as a different image. Any help is appreciated

Comment: It would be better to modify the image and push that instead of modifying a container, creating an image off that, and then pushing it.

Comment: I agree but I don't currently see a way around it due to how are configs are managed. They are essentially munged and I need to keep everything else the same. There's also no way to get all the labels for a particular tag from what I can see as I would've been able to build a similar image using the label information

Comment: For config files, it's very typical to bind-mount them into containers using a `docker run -v` option or similar.  For content built into an image you should _always_ use `docker build` to build a new image, but the way you're describing it, it probably shouldn't be part of the image.